# Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Tags: react-native

I upgraded node and Android studio.
After that when i run the application it's working in simulator but device not working.

it's showing below error,
Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Answer (score 0):

1.create directory  android/app/src/main/assets

2. run following command from project root directory

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

------------------------  OR ---------------------
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3. run again the command : react-native run-android

Follow below link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FEm1SjL1Vg

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the bundler first, run

> npm start

or

> react-native start

in the root of your project.

eg. in terminal:

> `cd project_name`

> project_name > `npm start`